# Facebook Graph API v10 image upload to Pages feed

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, filehandle

I'm trying to upload a image to facebook via graph api v10.
i have followed the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/resumable-upload-api/

I'm getting the File-Handle as result, but i dont know how to append this File-handle to my Page post. Does anyone know what i can do with this File-Handle to attach it to a Post I'm automatically posting after the file upload was successful?

Thanks!

Comment: Explained at the end of that page - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/resumable-upload-api/#page-thumbnails

Comment: There is an explanation on the Facebook API Docs, but it does not really help as it provides no information regarding where and how the received file handler can be used.

Answer (score 1):

I´ve got the same problem. In the Facebook Graph API Documentation it says:

> When we're done with uploading the data, you'll get a file handle:
>
> {"h":"2:c2FtcGxlLm1wNA==:image/jpeg:GKAj0gAUCZmJ1voFADip2iIAAAAAbugbAAAA:e:1472075513:ARZ_3ybzrQqEaluMUdI"}
>
> This value can be used in place of an uploaded file for subsequent
> graph calls.

However, no examples or further explanations are provided on how to use the received file handler.